# Select statement return false result with the subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, null, compare, subquery

I have CAPTURED_DATA_01 table which have following data:

```
SUBSCRIPTION_ID
201502031336444606
```

and WF_WORKFLOW table which has following data:

```
SUBSCRIPTION ID
201502031337330387
201502031336545536
201502031336444606
```

I have WF_WORKFLOW table in which i use subquery in order to get the result for SUBSCRIPTION_ID.The subquery runs fine.I want to compare the result of this SUBSCRIPTION_ID with the SUBSCRIPTION_ID of CAPTURED_DATA_01 table and return only results such that the SUBSCRIPTION_ID of WF_WORKKFLOW table greater than SUBSCRIPTION_ID of CAPTURED_DATA_01 table.So as given in both the data of the table the SUBSCRIPTION_ID from WF_WORKFLOW returns 2 rows with data `201502031336545536` and `201502031337330387`.
I have used the following query but it returns null. I dont know where i am doing the conditional mistake in my query. There is no problem with the subquery as i have tested it. The problem is only with the where condition where i am comparing the results. I think it should be properly defined.

```
Select * from(
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF,CAPTURED_DATA_01 CP
where WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID > CP.SUBSCRIPTION_ID and 
WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID IN
( 
select iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
from (
   SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
   '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '')) 
   AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
   FROM
   SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL 
   where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
) iw
where iw.order_type='SELF_REGISTRATION'
) 
and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0 order by wf.START_DATE desc)
```

Comment: Why the new account? Does your CLOB value have whitespace between the XML nodes?

Comment: Hello Alex. I dont know but i cant write a new question into my previous stackoverflow  account as my questions limit is exceeded it said. Thats why i have created a new account. No there is no whitespace between xml codes. I tested the subquery result first and mentioned the result in my code. Only i think the condition outside in clause fails. So once got the subscription ID from  subquery, i just want to compare this result with the result id CATURED_DATA_01 table.

Comment: I think Alex i should put the complete condition with this condition and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0 order by wf.START_DATE desc which return the SUBSCRIPTION_ID into ALIAS and then compare the result with the CAPTURED_DATA_01 table ?

Comment: What you have works for me, if I comment out the `where iw.order_type='SELF_REGISTRATION'` filter; so this isn't the full query you're running? ([SQL Fiddle without DB links](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b61cc/1))

Comment: No the condition where iw.order_type='SELF_REGISTRATION' comes under the subquery. If you remember my query yesterday the complete query is same as it is which gives the SUBSCRIPTION_ID. The only condition now i add in this is the comparision condition with the CAPTURE_DATA_01 table and after that it did not result anything.

Comment: Your edit removed that field from the subquery though. [It still works with it reinstated](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/734539/1). What does your [subquery return](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/734539/3)?

Comment: My subquery returns all the SUBSCRIPTION_ID with the specified conditions

Comment: This is strange Alex why i am returning the result as i have seen your fiddle. When i remove the CAPTURED_DATA_01 table with the comparision condition then the query runs and returns all the SUBSCRIPTION_ID as i have expected.

Comment: Just want to confirm the condition which i used and where i have used is it the correct one for comparision?

Comment: Since it works on my Fiddle, then yes. Maybe your CP doesn't have the (committed) data you think it does.

Comment: I think yes Alex but not sure. I am using Oracle SQL Developer. I will close the connection and try it again.

Comment: Hello Alex it works now the same query. I am really wondered what was the issue . Is the problem of remote link/database link or connection . But the query was running on the background without any error.

Comment: I can only imagine it was uncommitted data. Nothing to suggest the link or connection where a problem.

Comment: Hello Alex i have one more small question when i tried to retrieve order_number as well in main select statement using this condition i received an error cannot use LOB locators selectors from remote tables: select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,WF.START_DATE,   TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:orderNumber>\d+</ax2147:orderNumber> '), 
   '<ax2147:orderNumber>', ''), '</ax2147:orderNumber> ', '')) 
   AS ORDER_NUMBER

Comment: That's not a small question. You're getting the order number in the answer you posted and that works. Not sure how you're looking at WF and RESPONSE_XML at the same level of query now though, unless you're trying to include the raw column value in the subquery, but you haven't shown that.

Comment: Because i also want to insert this order number in CAPTURED_DATA_01 table which is inside in my subquery thats why i am trying for it to include in select clause